# bootstrap pop over with form elements inside using with jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage using Bootstrap.  What I attempting to do is have the user enter two(2) pieces of data into a Pop over ( much like a log-in ).  When the form is coded with html on page it works fine.  Problem: I am dynamically creating 2 (  )  elements  with jQuery.  jQuery can’t seem to find the  elements to append to the pop over.   I assume since they are dynamic and not static elements.  The pop over does not load properly and is not formatted and located correctly.  Once I am able to get the pop over to work, I will then attempt to retrieve form data for an ajax call.  Here is my code:

```
<body>

<div id="newForm"></div>

<!--  NOTE: image clicked below for popover to appear --> 

<div 
  style="position:absolute;left:230px;top:178px;width:120px;height:125px;">
        <a href="#" id="plus-circle">
             <img src="images/plus-circle-black.png">
        </a>
</div>

<script>   

    var idMtl = "mtlID";
    var idPrice = "mtlPrice";

 $(function() {

    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()

    <!--  dynamic form elements created --> 
    inputMtlID = document.createElement("input");
    inputMtlPR = document.createElement("input");
    inputMtlID.setAttribute('id', idMtl);   
    inputMtlID.setAttribute('id', idPrice); 
    $("#newForm").append(inputMtlID);
    $("#newForm").append("<br>");
    $("#newForm").append("<br>");
    $("#newForm").append(inputMtlPR);

  })

   $(function() {

          $('#plus-circle').popover({

            delay: { "show": 500 },
            placement: 'top',
                    container: 'body',
            title: 'Change Mtl Price (Fixed to DataBase)',
            html:true,
            content: $("#newForm").html()

      })
    })


</script>
```

Thank you in advance for any help on this question.   James

Comment: you can't retrieve data from your popover?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code, and it worked fairly for me. You can improve the design inside the popover with css within `style` attribute, deal with it like it was something in the *DOM* (You know what I mean)

Data from popover can be retrieving like that: [Source](https://gist.github.com/martinnormark/4466472)

```
$(document).on("click","#submit-form-inside-popover",function(){
    var popoverContent = $("#plus-circle").data("bs.popover").tip().find('.popover-content');
    var input = $('input:eq(0)',popoverContent).val();
    var input2 = $('.class_name',popoverContent).val();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I will give it a try.  I knew it needed a some additional jQuery code.